# PHP cURL - Bullhorn API sesison key

Tags: php, api, session, curl

I am using PHP cURL to use bullhorn API to access their services.

The procedure is as following :

- Make an API call to get access key.
- Using that access key, make another API call to get session key.
- That session key is validate for next few seconds/minutes.
- Using that session key, make other API calls to access the database. [Create new records / Get some records / Update records]

Here, when I want to perform any action to access bullhorn service, I have to follow above steps. Means I am making 3-4 API calls

The problem I am facing is, I am not getting, how to check whether the previous session key is valid / available so that, I can fire the last step directy. If that session key is not valid / available then, I will follow all the steps.

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly Check session key is expired or not ? Using the below API Call.

**{corpToken}/ping**

Sample API CALL and Response :

https://rest.bullhorn.com/rest-services/e999/ping

Response

{
"sessionExpires" : 1323449994922
}

Answer (score 0):

The API call that returns the 'access_token' also returns an 'expires_in' value.

The 'expires_in' + time() is the point that the access token is no longer valid.
Store this value.. ..as $expiryTime

So, before each call, check that $expiryTime > time().

If true.. ..continue.

Else, re-authenticate.